# how to pass values between pages in a React app using Redirect?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a simple app that should have a user type something in a form then after clicking the submit button it redirects to another page displaying whatever the user typed in. However, it is not working and I have no clue what to do. Redirect and this.prop.history.push does not work for me either. This is my code so far

My main application where the Router is:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';


import Login from './Login';
import Display from './Display';
import Header from './Header';


import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  
  state = {
     username: "DEFAULT"
  }
  
  addUser = (user) => {

    this.setState({username: user}) = () =>{
      window.href.location = "/display"
    }
  }



  render(){
    return (
      <Router>
         <div className='App'>
            <Header/>
            <Route exact path="/" render={props => (
            <p align='center'>WELCOME</p>
             )} /> 

            <Route exact path="/login" render={props => (
                <Login addUser={this.addUser}/>
              )} />
             <Route exact path="/display" render={props => (
                <Display username={this.state.username}/>
              )} /> 
         </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
 
}

export default App;
```

My Login page where the submit button should trigger a redirect

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';


 
class Login extends Component {


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            username: ""
        };
    }

    handleChange(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
    }

    handleSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.addUser(this.state.username) 
    }

    render(){

        return (
            <div>
                 <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <label>Username:</label>
                        <input 
                        type="text" name="username" 
                        value={this.state.username} 
                        onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                 </form>
                 
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Login;
```

and the page the renders what the user typed in:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
 
class Display extends Component {



    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                  {this.props.username}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Display;
```

with this I am able to redirect and update the state; the issue is that it does not display the updated state

Answer (score 0):

## 1. withRouter

use [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) to get this.props.history, use this.props.history.replace("/display") to redirect .

## 2. Render a Redirect

```
class Form extends React.Component {
   state = {redirect: null}
   goRedirect = ()=> this.setState({redirect: "/user/display"})
   render(){
      if (this.state.redirect){ return <Redirect to={this.state.redirect}/> }
      return <button onClick={this.goRedirect}>Go Redirect</button>
   }
}
```